# How to write search index with Google App Engine dev_appserver?

Tags: google-app-engine

I found such options in Google App Engine but not know how to write search indexes?

```
Search API:
  --search_indexes_path SEARCH_INDEXES_PATH
                        path to a file used to store search indexes (defaults
                        to a file in --storage_path if not set) (default:
                        None)
  --clear_search_indexes [CLEAR_SEARCH_INDEXES]
                        clear the search indexes (default: False)
```

How can I force to save indexes to file since it will be faster that recreating it each time application is loaded.

Comment: The search index gets saved to a file when you stop the server, and loaded from there when you start it. You don't need to run (or write) code to recreate the index each time, if that's what you're asking, but the server startup-time, as the index is loaded, is unavoidable.

Comment: It looks that search indexes is not saved under Win XP/7 Python27.

Comment: @Chameleon, it could be an IDE issue. For instance, when I rebuild my java GAE project in IntelliJ, it will erase my datastore and search index.

Comment: I analyzed code and it is bug related to Windows. GAE is use Unix signal to run shutdown. I Windows only possibility to run shutdown is to run dev_appserver from command line and use Ctrl-C. Such key is not available in Eclipse so it not possible to shutdown it.