# Search index automatically deleted on restart on appengine devserver for python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am developing on appengine  using the python sdk v 1.9.18 (the latest)

I am using the search api, while the server is running everything is ok, the index is created, and i can perform search and get result successfully, but when i restart the devserver the index is no longer there, it is deleted i think

start command line:

```
python.exe "C:/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" --host 127.0.0.1 .
```

on start up it logs:

```
WARNING  2015-04-01 11:53:53,005 simple_search_stub.py:1115] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\jos\appdata\local\temp\appengine.application\search_indexes
```

indeed the file is not there, and i do not know why it is deleted

any help please ?

Answer (score 3):

Does the development server output a successful search index save when you shutdown it ?

```
INFO     2015-04-01 12:51:35,396 api_server.py:591] Saving search indexes
```

It works on the OS X version, however it seems like some people are having the same issue due to Windows or the IDE you use (but you are apparently using the command line), see the question comments
[How to write search index with Google App Engine dev_appserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090607/how-to-write-search-index-with-google-app-engine-dev-appserver)

Comment: No, it does not !!
Is there a solution ?

Comment: Does it output an error while trying to save the search indexes ? It could help...

You can also try to change the search indexes path with option "--search_indexes_path". It might work, if the problem comes from the default path.

Comment: No, it does not seem to try to write it altogether, it just quites !
Any work-around to force it to write the index periodically instead of on shut down?